# Why this (group) MySQL query wont work

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this MySQL Query, I can't seem to have it work out. 
I wanted it to group "symbol" from the table "portfolio".
( `SELECT symbol FROM portfolio GROUP BY symbol` )
Though then I wanted it to limit its search to:
( `WHERE key = '$key' AND hash = '$hash' ORDER BY time DESC` )

In all, this is the entire Query, though it's giving me syntax errors when I run it, any help would be nice.

```
SELECT symbol FROM portfolio GROUP BY symbol WHERE username = '$username' AND hash = '$hash' ORDER BY time DESC;
```

Comment: Giving us the exact error messages would be nice, too.

Comment: just syntax up make Because you can't

Comment: @cale_b its a syntax error relating to the WHERE. (#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE username = '$username' AND hash = '$hash' ORDER BY time DESC
LIMIT 0, 25' at line 1 )

Comment: Isn't `time` a keyword?

Comment: @cale_b time may be a keyword, but it's not a reserved word

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GROUP BY` must go after (or before) `ORDER BY` clause.

Also, enclose time between `` so it won't conflict if it is a keyword in the SQL engine you are using.

Comment: Which is it.  After (or before)?

Comment: I said “or” because different implementations accept it in either or both side.

Comment: I've removed the ORDER BY in all, still will not work

Comment: Alec - different implementations of what - `mysql`?

Comment: @Shortland, I didn't say you should remove it, I said you should put GROUP BY clause right before or after ORDER BY.

Comment: @cale_b any SQL engine actually. Though I think MariaDB implementation differs a bit from Oracle's MySQL.

Comment: @Alec was under the impression that the ORDER BY was the error since you said it mattered where I put it, so I removed it in all to test.

Comment: No, no, I said that GROUP BY goes after or before ORDER BY, so you must rearrange so GROUP BY goes after or before it. Sometimes whichever will work.

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
SELECT symbol FROM portfolio  WHERE username = '$username' AND hash =   
'$hash' GROUP BY symbol ORDER BY time DESC;
```

Comment: I will +1 if you explain what you changed, and why it worked.

Comment: @cale_b Read it and compare, the WHERE clause comes first in his query

Comment: I can do that, @Shortland.  **I get the difference**.  My point is that the answer would be *far more helpful* if it explained *what was wrong and what the change is*.  SO guidelines recommend an explanation, and **not** code-only answers.

Comment: @cale_b, I explained the reason in my answer since the beginning (and answered first) though seems like nobody did much effort to try to understand it.
Seems like the days where the first correct answer would be picked are gone.

Comment: @Alec - I don't disagree.  FYI, I undersand the problem and answers, and am just here trying to help improve the quality of the site by encouraging new users like Ezhil to post better answers.  I haven't upvoted anything at all here, because your answer was a bit ambiguous, and this answer still doesn't explain why it works or what was different.